# Change the color of text of sliderInput in a shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny

Im trying to change the color only of the font of the values `(1,2,3,...10)` of the s`liderInput()` from black to white but it cannot happen. How is the slider is connected with the css file?

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "
      .irs-grid-text {font-family: 'arial'; color: white; bottom: 17px; z-index: 1;}
    "),
  sliderInput(inputId="test", label=NULL, min=1, max=10, value=5, step = 1, width='100%')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to change the background

Comment: They are being changed to have a white color font, and you can't see them because the background is also white.

Comment: Try with `tags$style(type = "text/css", "
      .irs-grid-text {font-family: 'arial'; color: white; bottom: 17px; z-index: 1;background-color: #007BA7;}
    "),`

Comment: Im doing it in rstudio cloud and they seem black to me yet. check the edit

Comment: I tried on rstudio.  It is changing for me though

Comment: the text color remains black

Comment: You are right, when running in RStudio cloud the font color isn't being changed, it appears your css is being overriden by css from a file named ion.rangeSlider.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add !important to the CSS to get it to work, not ideal I know - perhaps using an external file for your CSS might work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML(type = "text/css", "
      .irs-grid-text {font-family: 'arial'; color: white !important; bottom: 17px; z-index: 1; }
    "))),
  sliderInput(inputId="test", label=NULL, min=1, max=10, value=5, step = 1, width='100%')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can put `.js-irs-0` in the CSS to reference your slider.  I put red for display purpose.

```
color = "orange"
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "
     .js-irs-0 .irs-grid-text {font-family: 'arial'; color: red; bottom: 1px; z-index: 1;}
    "),
  setSliderColor(color,c(1)),
  sliderInput(inputId="test", label=NULL, min=1, max=10, value=5, step = 1, width='100%')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

[image: output]